# Nikon D3200 Android USB control

Tags: nikon, android, nikon-d3200, android-app

I have a tablet having Android operating system, and a Nikon D3200 camera.
I was wondering if there is any way to connect them together so that I can use the tablet as a remote control. I have already done this on my PC (using digiCamControl).

Would it be possible to connect those two devices with an USB cable and take pictures with an application on the Android device? Does something like this already exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it would depend on what Android device you have. DslrDashboard claims to support it on some Android devices:

> To be able to use the application with your USB connected DSLR you will need an Android device that supports the USB host function and an USB OTG adapter that you can buy cheap on internet or build it yourself.

The application is free, GPLv3-licensed, and can be found here:

- https://code.google.com/p/dslrdashboard/
- Play store link:
  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dslr.dashboard

Comment: Can't speak for the D3200, but it works fine on with my D300.

Comment: @Blrfl The D300 supports tethering with a variety of applications, the D3x00 series does not.

Answer (score 0):

I have an android tablet and I use an APP from nikon that can remotely access the photos on the camera and also remotely take pictures, search google play store for MWU nikon photo app, it's also on my IPHONE as well.