# Can Snapbridge, with a Nikon D3500, let you see what the camera lens sees?

Tags: nikon, snapbridge

On a Nikon D3500 is it possible, on Snapbridge, to see the what the camera lens sees before the picture is taken? If so how?

Comment: Do you mean Nikon D3500?

Comment: Do you mean if you can activate a Live View inside Snapbridge so you see a live image through your lense?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, unless Nikon has changed the way they do the D3x00 series. We've got a number of related questions that all deal with the D3x00 series of cameras not having the ability to do tethered shooting. Even Nikon cameras that are capable of tethered shooting don't give real time Live Views off camera with the major tethering software applications. There are some other apps that claim they can do it with upper tier Nikon cameras, such as the D7x00 series or the three digit (D850, D300, etc.) and single digit (D5, D4,etc.) models.

[Is there a way to replicate Nikon D3100 live view on my laptop screen?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/36130/15871)
[Can I tether my Nikon D3200 to Lightroom?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/82870/15871)
[how could I duplicate my Nikon D5300 live view on both my PC and camera itself?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/97170/15871)
[Can I live view my Nikon D3200 via laptop/ tablet etc?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/59842/15871)
[Is Nikon D3200 compatible with external monitor?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/96427/15871)
[How can I use live view while tethering a Nikon D810 to LightRoom 5 CC?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/67972/15871)
[Are there any free Windows programs to get a live view for a Nikon D700 in tethered capture mode?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/15383/15871)
[Nikon D3200 Android USB control](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/53734/15871)